# Derivation of F distribution from quotient distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, f-distribution

I'm looking for the derivation of the F distribution. There is a fairly understandable (for me) derivation presented on this site: http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/pdfc-fdist.htm.

On this site, the derivation is as follows:

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, with PDFs $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

> Suppose also that the random variable X is always nonnegative.

> ...consider the random variable defined by the quotient $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$.

Then,

$$f_{XY}(z) = \int_0^\infty x f_X(x) f_Y(xz) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

> Let $X$ and $Y$ both have independent chi-square distributions, with degrees of freedom $n$ and $m$ respectively.

So,

$$f_Z(z) = \dfrac{ \Gamma\left(\dfrac{m+n}{2}\right) z^{m/2-1}}{ 
    \Gamma\left(\dfrac{m}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right) (z+1)^{(m+n)/2}}$$

The question is in this part:

> The F-Distribution is actually not this quotient, but the quotient   $F=\frac{Y/m}{X/n}$.   Therefore, if X is a random variable with an F-Distribution, its PDF is

$$f_X(x) = \color{red}{\dfrac{m}{n} f_Z \left( \dfrac{m}{n} x\right)} \\
  = \dfrac{ \dfrac{m}{n} \Gamma\left(\dfrac{m+n}{2}\right) \left( \dfrac{m}{n} x\right)^{m/2-1}}{
    \Gamma\left(\dfrac{m}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right) 
    \left( \dfrac{m}{n} x + 1\right)^{(m+n)/2}} \\
  = \dfrac{ \Gamma\left(\dfrac{m+n}{2}\right) \left(\dfrac{m}{n}\right)^{m/2} x^{m/2-1}}{
    \Gamma\left(\dfrac{m}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)
    \left(1 + \dfrac{m}{n} x\right)^{(m+n)/2}}$$

I understand that if random variable $A=\frac{Y/m}{X/n}$, and $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$, then, $\frac{m}{n}A=Z \rightarrow \frac{n}{m}Z=A$. So, If PDF of Z is $f_Z(z)$, shouldn't

$$f_A(a) = \dfrac{n}{m} f_Z \left( \dfrac{m}{n} a\right) \cdots what\ I feel\ correct$$

instead of

$$f_A(a) = \dfrac{m}{n} f_Z \left( \dfrac{m}{n} a\right) \cdots web\ site\ explanation$$
?

The result on web site is correct, so my understanding is probably wrong, but I spend fairly long time for this part but can't come up with the explanation.

Comment: If $x=\frac{n}{m}z$ then $z=\frac{m}{n}x$ and $\text dz=\frac{m}{n}\text dx$ .

Comment: @Xi'an: Thanks a lot for the comment. Yes, that makes sense.